# Selenium Python XPATH I am trying to select a drop down from the 3rd column of a table where name is in the 1st column

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with some rows and columns.  I would like to select the drop down element where the name is "Mobile".  The Name is in col1 and the drop down is in col3
Using XPATH I can find the Name "Mobile", I need to get to col3 so I can select the drop down element.
I tried to use the axis "following" but this highlights all the drop down elements from col3.  I am close, I just need to get the drop down which belongs to the Name Mobile.

This is my XPATH:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"]//td//div//span[text()="MOBILE"]//following::td//div//select
```

This is some of the HTML:

```
<table id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH GJPPK2LBGH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-307" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow36"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-308" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span title="PHONE" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">PHONE</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-309" style="outline-style:none;">
            <select tabindex="-1">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-310" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_details_cb_phone" type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="11">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBHG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-307" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow36"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-308" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span title="MOBILE" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">MOBILE</span>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-309" style="outline-style:none;">
                <select tabindex="-1">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBBH">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="12">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-307" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="radio" name="rbCrossRow36"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-308" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span title="DOB" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DOB</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">  
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="13">

</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I think I have solved it.  I have tried putting td[1] after the following axis.  It has highlighted the 1 drop down element in the same row where Name is "Mobile"

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_mapping_tab_mappings_ct_mapping_body"]//td//div//span[text()="MOBILE"]//following::td[1]//div//select
```